# why there is a blank space on second column of MS WORD

Tags: microsoft-word

Don't know why, I have a blank space on second column typed in MS Word.
Here is the download link of the sample page.

[Download link of the MS Word file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/teq08ly9c30atjc/sssp-form-5.docx?dl=0)

Please let me know how to resolve this issue so that top of the both first and second columns will be in equal place.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first column occupies the entire line behind it, although there is no text, it still occupies the position.

[image]

You just need to drag the second column behind the first column, and you can refer to the screen record:

[image]

Comment: Yep - there is a line break after the "compressed Air Equipment" heading. Removing it gives the following: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/15v60pbuyx0h55ef249w8/sssp-form-5-1.docx?dl=0&rlkey=uki4fk4puu5o87ygvcd3jrwnz  nice one @Binggo_MSFT